# Ruby Terminal -e: making decisions based on $_ comparisons

Tags: ruby, terminal

This is my code, it runs but does nothing.

```
ls | ruby -ne 'File.delete($_) if File.extname($_)==".jpg"'
```

I thought it was string comparisons issue but the below code works.

```
ruby -e 'puts "dsad" if "e" == "e"'
```

This leads me to believe **$_** is a different **Type**. How do I run comparison on it, specifically as it relates to my initial code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the newlines.

```
ls | ruby -ne 'File.delete($_.chomp) if File.extname($_.chomp)==".jpg"'
```

Comment: You can also call `chomp` right at the beginning. (without receiver)